# is it possible to use two .haccess files or multiply rules?

Tags: .htaccess

I have created an url shortener tha use .htaccess file to redirect the traffic,
I had the files placed in a sub directory called urls, so after i generated an url the link would become something like this

www.homepage.com/urls/i74a

Now i want to move the files to the main folder so the generated url would look something like this
www.homepage.com/i74a

But my problem is that i have WordPress installed and they have their own .htaccess with some rules.

is it possible to combine this two?

I was thinking something like this, but i cant get i to work.

.htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

#Begin SHORTENER#
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -MultiViews  
RewriteRule ^url\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w\d]{4})$ redirect.php?code=$1 [L]

#END SHORTENER#
```

Comment: You do not know if that link corresponds to the Wordpress or your script, you have to make some difference to recognize it directly by URL. If you know that WP can not have 4 letter pages, put your rule above its, but after `RewriteEngine On` and `RewruteBase /`

Comment: @Cheery Im not sure if I understand.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/X1vJWgke